# Return object from class member function in C++

Tags: c++, function, object

The task is in the above code to write member function that calculate new point, which is amount of two other points. And i dont know how to return object or what should i do. Here is the code, and the function is marked with three !!!. The function must return something, i cant make it void because reference to void is unallowed.

```
    class point {
    private:
        float x;
        float y;
    public:
        point();
        point(float xcoord, float ycoord);
        void print();
        float dist(point p1, point p2);
    !!! float &add(point p1, point p2);
        float  &X();
        float &Y();
        ~point();
    };
    float & point::X() { return x; }
    float & point::Y() { return y; }
    point::point() {
        cout << "Creating POINT (0,0)" << endl;
        x = y = 0.0;
    }
    point::point(float xcoord, float ycoord) {
        cout << "Creating POINt (" << xcoord << "," << ycoord << ")" << endl;
        x = xcoord;
        y = ycoord;
    }
    void point::print() {
        cout << "POINT (" << x << "," << y << ")";
    }
    float point::dist(point p1, point p2) {
        return sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y));
    }
   !!!// float & point::add(point p1, point p2) {
        point z;
        z.X() = p1.X() + p2.X();
        z.Y() = p1.Y() + p2.Y();
        z.print();
    }
    point::~point() {
        cout << "Deleting ";
        print();
        cout << endl;
    }
    int main() {
        point a(3, 4), b(10, 4);
        cout << "Distance between"; a.print();
        cout << " and "; b.print();
        cout << " is " << a.dist(a, b) << endl;
    }
```

i make it ! here is what must be add function

```
//prototype

    point &add(point& p1, point& p2);
//function itself

    point & point::add(point& p1, point& p2) {
        point z;
        z.x = p1.X() + p2.X();
        z.y = p1.Y() + p2.Y();
        z.print();
        return z;
    }
```

Many thanks to ForceBru!! and all of you

Comment: if you add two `point`s most likely you want to return a `point`, no?

Comment: it is not clear what is your question, if you want to return an object from a member function, just do it....

Comment: and btw returning references to private members breaks encapsulation, such that you could as well make the members public. I would suggest to either make them public from the start or return values from the getters

Comment: @tobi303 is right, try declaring point add(point x, pointy); Then in the method result = new point();.... return result

Comment: @ChrisR actually I was referring to his `X()` and `Y()` methods

Comment: __Do not__ return reference to an object that's inside your `add` function.

Answer (score 4):

### What to do

You can return a `point` as well:

```
point point::add(const point& p1, const point& p2) {
    point result;

    result.x = p1.x + p2.x;
    result.y = p1.y + p2.y;

    return result;
}
```

Note that there's no need to use `X()` and `Y()` functions here since this method already has access to the private members.

It's also possible to do an operator overload

```
/*friend*/ point operator+ (const point& one, const point& two) {
    // the code is the same
}
```

### How to use it

```
int main() {
    point one(2,5), two(3,6), three;

    three.add(one, two);

    std::cout << "Added " << one.print() << " and " << two.print();
    std::cout << " and got " << three.print() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**: as it was said in the comments, you shouldn't return a reference to an object *created inside your `add` function* since in such a situation you're allowed to return references to class members and to `static` variables only.

Comment: you could mention that by no means he should return a reference to `result`. In his code it looks like this would be his approach

Comment: Perhaps you can help by extending the answer to show how he would use it in the calling code. i.e. the last 5 lines of the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use Operator overloading here:

```
point point::operator+(const point & obj)  {

point obj3;
obj3.x = this->x + obj.x;
return obj3;
```

}

returning object with Addition of two points.

for simple example :

```
class Addition  {
int a;
public:
      void SetValue(int x);
      int GetValue();
      Addition operator+(const Addition & obj1);
};
void Addition::SetValue(int x)
{
    a = x;
}
int Addition::GetValue()
{
   return a;
 }
Addition Addition::operator+(const Addition &obj1)
{
  Addition obj3;
  obj3.a = this->a + obj1.a;
  return obj3;
 }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  Addition obj1;
  int Temp;
  std::cout<<"Enter Value for First Object : "<<std::endl;
  std::cin>>Temp;

  obj1.SetValue(Temp);

  Addition obj2;
  std::cout<<"Enter Value for Second Object : "<<std::endl;
  std::cin>>Temp;

  obj2.SetValue(Temp);

  Addition obj3;
  obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
  std::cout<<"Addition of point is "<<obj3.GetValue()<<std::endl;

  return 0;
```

}